# What is the problem in this code? (Python)

Tags: python

```
rain = input("Is it currently raining? ")

if rain == 'Yes':
  print("You should take the bus.")

elif rain == 'No':
  travel = input("How far in km do you need to travel? ")
  if travel <= '2' and >= '10':
    print("You should ride your bike.")
  elif travel > '2':
    print("You should walk.")
  elif travel < '10':
    print("You should take the bus.")
```

in this code it will ask the user is it raining and if it is it is going to tell the user to go by bus but if you say no it is not raining it will ask you how far you need to travel in km and if it is lower than two it will tell you should walk, if it is higher than two but lower than ten it will tell you should bike, finally if it is higher than ten it will tell you to take the bus

Comment: You should convert the travel distance to an integer before comparing it.

Comment: the logic doesn't make sense, how can you have <=2 and >=10

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! I am wondering what your actual question is here. The code you provided has a syntax error when I try to run it.

Comment: Have you tried running your code? What problem did you run into?

Comment: File "program.py", line 7
    if travel <= 2 and >= 10:
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: i am asking what the problem is with the syntax

Comment: correct line number 7 as **if travel <= '2' and travel>= '10':**

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `travel` to a number in order to do numeric comparisons. Otherwise it will do lexicographic comparison, in which case `'9' > '10'`, for example.

And to compare with two numbers, you have to specify the variable again. You also seem to have gotten your comparisons all backwards.

```
  travel = int(input("How far in km do you need to travel? "))
  if travel >= 2 and travel <= 10:
    print("You should ride your bike.")
  elif travel < 2:
    print("You should walk.")
  elif travel > 10:
    print("You should take the bus.")
```

`travel >= 2 and travel <= '10'` can also be simplified to `2 <= travel <= 10`